# Hard disk makes noise under Windows

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I have a hard disk that periodically makes strange sounds. The thing is that this happens only
when I am under Windows Server 2008. When I use Debian Linux the disk works silently. So, it can be inferred from this that it's not the hardware problem, but software. Windows shows that the hard disk's driver is up to date. The noise is like the drive turns off and then immediately turns on. It lasts half a second. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

1) Entire Windows Server 2008 system is placed on another good old HDD that have no problems. The noisy disk is just a storage.

2) Power saving option for HDD is turned off (If you did mean "Turn off hard disk after:" option in Advanced Settings of Power Options. It is set to "Never")

That means that the first 3 comments does not solve the problem and issue is still open.

Comment: Without actually hearing it:
My guess would be a failing actuator and the Windows Data is simply located on the drive physically where the actuator motor is having issues parking / reading etc.

Comment: Do you have any powersaving options set in Windows Server 2008 which might put your harddisk to sleep?

Comment: Its entirely possible for a drive to have bad sectors that are only accessed when using Windows since the Windows system files would never be read while running Debian.  Verify the disk is healthy.

Comment: Question updated